# How can i compare three array of objects so i an add or remove new values?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have three array of objects. The first array of objects is the `original state`.

```
let originalArrState = [
    {
        id:1,
        name:'Name 1 from id 1',
        number: 15 // => this needs to be removed based on the value `number`
        // in secondArrCompare - because we have there object with id of 1
    },
    {
        id:1,
        name:'Name 2 from id 1',
        number: 125
    },
    {
        id:1,
        name:'Name 3 from id 1',
        number: 130
    },

    // 135 needs to be added based on the value `number` in firstArrCompare because we have there 
    // object with id of 1
]
```

now i have other two array of objects which i need to compare them with the original arr

```
let firstArrCompare = [
    {
        id:1,
        number:135
    }
]

let secondArrCompare = [
    {
        id:1,
        number:15
    }
]
```

the idea is that it needs to be dynamically - so based on the values in `secondArrCompare` we need to remove objects from `originalArrState`  and based on the `firstArrCompare` we need to add new one after we remove the previous.

So the result should be at the end array of objects with values `125 130 135`.

```
let originalArrState = [
    {
        id:1,
        name:'Name 2 from id 1',
        number: 125
    },
    {
        id:1,
        name:'Name 3 from id 1',
        number: 130
    },
    {
        id:1,
        number: 135
    },
]
```

If `firstArrCompare`  and `secondArrCompare` are empty than nothing should be added or removed.
The values inside will be always one to one - so one value with same id in firstArrCompare and one in secondArrCompare.

Also there could be multiply objects with anotber id - for example `id-2` which will mutate the original state.

For example

```
let firstArrCompare = [
    {
        id:1,
        number:135
    },
    {
        id:2,
        number:1000
    }
    // we search for id 2 in original arr so we can add this after the removing
]

let secondArrCompare = [
    {
        id:1,
        number:15
    },
    {
        id:2,
        number:100
    }
    // now we need to search for id 2 in original arr to remove that
]
```

So if there is id 1 in first arr, there will be always object with id 1 in the second array - so one to one relationship.

**i got stuck at**

```
 var newArr = originalArrState.filter(itemOne => {
        return !secondArrCompare.some(itemTwo => {
          return itemOne.id == itemTwo.id;
        })
      })
```

Comment: so in the second example final array has `{
        id:1,
        name:'Name 2 from id 1',
        number: 125
    },
    {
        id:1,
        name:'Name 3 from id 1',
        number: 130
    },     {
        id:1,
        number:135
    },
    {
        id:2,
        number:1000
    }` ?

Comment: sorry, it's still not clear for me. in your originalArrState you have objects with the same id and different names?

Comment: Can we assume that uniqueness is determined by the combination `id`/`number`? Because `secondArrCompare` only the array element that matches both the `id` and `number`. Not all elements with `id` `1` are deleted.

Comment: @3limin4t0r They are unique yes

Comment: @cmgchess Yes. The second examle should look like that if there is object with id2 in the original array

Comment: @sparrow123 if the original array is like the one given at very top should the second example still be `[{
  id: 1,
  name: "Name 2 from id 1",
  number: 125
}, {
  id: 1,
  name: "Name 3 from id 1",
  number: 130
}, {
  id: 1,
  number: 135
}]`

Comment: @cmgchess yes, i just added an example that there could be another objects with other id, but original array stays same with this data set - as you writed because there is no id 2 in the original array. Do you have any idea how can be this solved ?

Comment: so is it like 1. remove all from `originalArrState` where id and number are same in `secondArrCompare` to get `newArr`. 2. for all in `firstArrCompare` if id in `newArr` then add to `newArr` ?

Comment: @cmgchess Yes buddy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doing some changes to your implementation. Had to filter both `id` and `number` combination matches otherwise all elements with `id:1` will be removed. We get `newArr` from this.
After that looped over the `firstArrCompare` and add to the `newArray` if element with same `id` is present in `newArr`

```js
let originalArrState = [{
        id: 1,
        name: 'Name 1 from id 1',
        number: 15
    },
    {
        id: 1,
        name: 'Name 2 from id 1',
        number: 125
    },
    {
        id: 1,
        name: 'Name 3 from id 1',
        number: 130
    },
]

let firstArrCompare = [{
        id: 1,
        number: 135
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        number: 1000
    }
]

let secondArrCompare = [{
        id: 1,
        number: 15
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        number: 100
    }
]

var newArr = originalArrState.filter(itemOne => {
    return !secondArrCompare.some(itemTwo => {
        return itemOne.id === itemTwo.id && itemOne.number === itemTwo.number;
    })
})
firstArrCompare.forEach((el) => {
    if (newArr.some((item) => item.id===el.id)){
    newArr.push(el)
  }
})

console.log(newArr)
```

Comment: If i add  {
        id:2,
        number: 5
    }, into the original araay, than it is broken andi get two objects in the original array with id of 2 instead of one, so removing the old one and add new one

Comment: on what basis should i remove `{ id:2, number: 5 }`. if i do the check with `id` only in the filter then all elements with `id: 1` get removed. can you give an example and an expected output?

Comment: My mistake. I accepted your answer

Comment: if anything goes wrong put a comment